# Swing application does not display anything

Tags: java, swing, awt

I am currently trying to create a simple dodge game using Java Swing and AWT. Right now, I have created some simple outline code to test if the concept I am trying to create will work. I have used polymorphism to try to create multiple types of object Enemy which will have individual draw() and act() code that makes them be drawn by AWT and then move in a specific fashion based on what type they are. I imported Graphics2D to draw() in an attempt to make the code more reusable. I then used a while loop to run the Java Swing/AWT built-in thread to allow animations for the enemies. However, when I run the code, it compiles correctly, but only a blank screen is displayed.

[image: Java Swing output]

How can I fix it?

Here is the code I used. The code involving the Mouse is incomplete.

Game.java

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Game extends JPanel {
    //FPS Setup
    int fps = 30; //FPS
    int secConst = 1000; //milliseconds per second
    int frmConst = (int) Math.floor((double) secConst / (double) fps); //delay between frames

    //FRAME Setup
    String appName = "Dodge This"; //app name
    int frameW = 500; //frame width
    int frameH = 500; //frame height

    //ENEMY TEST
    //TO REPLACE WITH ARRAY OF ENEMIES
    Square square = new Square(0, 100, 0, 10);
    Circle circle = new Circle(50, 50, 10);
    boolean lose = true;

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        //TO REPLACE WITH LOOP THROUGH ARRAY OF ENEMIES
        square.act();
        square.draw(g2d);
        circle.act();
        circle.draw(g2d);

        if (this.lose) {
            g2d.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 0));
            g2d.setFont(new Font("Sans Serif", Font.PLAIN, 32));
            g2d.drawString("You Lose", 0, 0); //TO REPLACE WITH RANDOMIZED LOSE MESSAGE
            }
        }

    public static void main(String [] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Game game = new Game();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame(game.appName);
        frame.setSize(game.frameW, game.frameH);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        while (true) {
            if (MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().equals(new Point(game.circle.getX(), game.circle.getY())) && MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().equals(new Point(game.square.getX(), game.square.getY()))) {
                game.lose = true;
                break;
                }

            game.repaint();
            Thread.sleep(game.frmConst);
            }
        }
    }
```

Enemy.java

```
import java.awt.*;

public abstract class Enemy {
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public double direction;
    public double speed;

    //BASIC METHODS
    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
        }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
        }
    
    public void setDirection(double direction) {
        this.direction = direction;
        }
    
    public void setSpeed(double speed) {
        this.speed = speed;
        }

    public int getX() {
        return this.x;
        }

    public int getY() {
        return this.y;
        }
    
    public double getDirection() {
        return this.direction;
        }
    
    public double getSpeed() {
        return this.speed;
        }

    //METHODS FOR UNIQUE ENEMIES
    public abstract void act();

    public abstract void draw(Graphics2D g2d);
    }
```

Square.java

```
import java.awt.*;

public class Square extends Enemy{
    //CONSTRUCTORS
    public Square() {
        this.x = 0;
        this.y = 0;
        this.direction = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * 8) * 45;
        this.speed = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * 15);
        } //default constructor

    public Square(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.direction = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * 8) * 45;
        this.speed = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * 15);
        }
    
    public Square(int x, int y, double direction) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.direction = direction;
        this.speed = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * 15);
        }
    
    public Square(int x, int y, double direction, double speed) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.direction = direction;
        this.speed = speed;
        }

    //ACTIONS
    @Override
    public void act() {
        this.x += Math.floor(this.speed * (Math.cos(this.direction)));
        this.y += Math.floor(this.speed * -1 * (Math.sin(this.direction)));
        }
    
    @Override
    public void draw(Graphics2D g2d) {
        g2d.setColor(new Color(100, 100, 100));
        g2d.fillRect(this.x, this.y, 50, 50);
        }
    }
```

Circle.java

```
import java.awt.*;

public class Circle extends Enemy{
    double mouseX;
    double mouseY;

    //CONSTRUCTORS
    public Circle() {
        this.x = 0;
        this.y = 0;
        this.direction = 0;
        this.speed = 5;
        } //default constructor

    public Circle(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.direction = 0;
        this.speed = 5; 
        }
    
    public Circle (int x, int y, int speed) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.direction = 0;
        this.speed = speed;
        }

    //ACTIONS
    @Override
    public void act() {
        this.mouseX = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getX();
        this.mouseY = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getY();

        this.x += this.speed * Math.floor(Math.abs(this.y - this.mouseY) / Math.abs(this.x - this.mouseX));
        this.y += this.speed * -1 * Math.floor(Math.abs(this.x - this.mouseX) / Math.abs(this.y - this.mouseY));
        }
    
    @Override
    public void draw(Graphics2D g2d) {
        g2d.setColor(new Color(50, 50, 50));
        g2d.fillOval(this.x, this.y, 10, 10);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You don't seem to be adding your `Game` panel to the frame.

Comment: Swing is not thread safe, you're "wild" `while-loop` is going to cause a number of issues.  `MouseInfo` isn't really the best choice for monitoring the mouse position, as you'd need to convert the coordinates from the screen context to the component context, better make use of the various `MouseListener`s instead.  I'd also recommend against overriding `paint` and, as a general preference, override `paintComponent` instead.  All of these things are going to require to change the way you are thinking about your problem

Comment: Under no circumstances should `square.act()` and `circle.act()` be inside a painting method.  You do not control when painting occurs;  the system does.  All sorts of things beyond your control can trigger painting, including moving the window and even moving the mouse over the window.

Comment: @khelwood I can't believe I forgot to add that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the following code for some improvements in the program structure as well as better use of `Swing` tools. Note the comments:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Game extends JPanel {
    //FPS Setup
    int fps = 3; // FPS (slow for testing)
    int secConst = 1000; //milliseconds per second
    int frmConst = secConst / fps; //delay between frames
    private Timer timer;

    String appName = "Dodge This"; //app name
    int frameW = 500, frameH = 500; //frame width and height

    Square square = new Square(0, 100, 0., 10.);
    Circle circle = new Circle(50, 50, 0., 10.);
    boolean lose = false; //the correct state at start ;

    //override  paintComponent rather than  paint
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        square.draw(g2d);
        circle.draw(g2d);

        if (lose) {
            g2d.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 0));
            g2d.setFont(new Font("Sans Serif", Font.PLAIN, 32));
            g2d.drawString("You Lose", 0, 0);
        }
    }

    public void start(){
        //use swing timer to invoke game cycles
        if(timer != null && timer.isRunning()) {
            timer.stop();
        }

        timer = new Timer(frmConst, e->{
                if(lose) {
                    timer.stop();
                } else {
                    play();
                }
            }
        );

        timer.start();
    }

    public void play(){
        square.act();
        circle.act();
        //lose criteria (not sure what are you trying to check)
        if (MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().equals(new Point(circle.getX(), circle.getY()))
                && MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().equals(new Point(square.getX(), square.getY()))) {
            lose = true;
        }
        repaint();
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Game game = new Game();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame(game.appName);
        frame.setSize(game.frameW, game.frameH);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(game);// add game to frame

        game.start();
    }
}

abstract class Enemy {
    public int x,y;
    public double direction, speed;

    public Enemy(int x, int y, double speed) {
        this(x,y,0, speed);
    }

    public Enemy(int x, int y, double direction, double speed) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.direction = direction;
        this.speed = speed;
    }

    //BASIC METHODS
    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void setDirection(double direction) {
        this.direction = direction;
    }

    public void setSpeed(double speed) {
        this.speed = speed;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public double getDirection() {
        return direction;
    }

    public double getSpeed() {
        return speed;
    }

    //METHODS FOR UNIQUE ENEMIES
    public abstract void act();

    public abstract void draw(Graphics2D g2d);
}

class Square extends Enemy{

    public Square(int x, int y, double direction, double speed) {
        super(x, y, direction, speed);
    }

    @Override
    public void act() {
        x += Math.floor(speed * Math.cos(direction));
        y += Math.floor(speed * -1 * Math.sin(direction));
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Graphics2D g2d) {
        g2d.setColor(new Color(100, 100, 100));
        g2d.fillRect(x, y, 50, 50);
    }
}

class Circle extends Enemy{
    double mouseX, mouseY;

    public Circle(int x, int y, double direction, double speed) {
        super(x, y, direction, speed);
    }

    @Override
    public void act() {
        mouseX = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getX();
        mouseY = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getY();

        x += speed * Math.floor(Math.abs(y - mouseY) / Math.abs(x - mouseX));
        y += speed * -1 * Math.floor(Math.abs(x - mouseX) / Math.abs(y - mouseY));
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Graphics2D g2d) {
        g2d.setColor(new Color(50, 50, 50));
        g2d.fillOval(x, y, 10, 10);
    }
}
```

(Run it online [here](https://replit.com/@c0derrepo/UnFinishedGame#Main.java))